# Laravel array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array In ServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, array-merge

I can not do php artisan serve anymore, it says :

> In ServiceProvider.php line 59:
>
> ```
>    array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
> ```

Line 59 code is in ServiceProvider.php:

```
$this->app['config']->set($key, array_merge(require $path, $config));
```

I dont understand what is wrong with my ServiceProvider.php, I did not change a thing there.

I hope some can help me.

Comment: Error says `$config` is not array

Comment: what is a $config??

Comment: Show your service register method

Comment: Is this from `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php`? Wouldn't change anything there. Check if all your config files are valid

Comment: yes it if from `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php`

Comment: You must  be check your `config/*.php` folder all configuration files return array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one

used `is_array` method here.

```
$this->app['config']->set($key, array_merge(require $path, is_array($config) ? $config : [$config]))

is_array($config) ? $config : [$config]
```

> if do not want change on framework file check configration files in your
>   `config` folder one the file return **single value** not an **array** (must be
>   return array)

Comment: Don't make any change in that file. The problem is surely somewhere else. Read the error message carefully, see the log and add the errors in your question.

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot, I had to generate a key after. But it worked!

Comment: I recommend to _NOT_ edit the file `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php`, this is a Laravel core file and might/will be overwritten on the next composer update - all your modifications will be lost.

Answer (score 11):

Check the files in your `config/` folder, one of them is not returning an array.

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: this is crt answer. @Jignesh Joisar

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Any new installation via Composer for some package may cause a conflict in file under vendor.

So remove the lastly installed package via  "composer.json" in "require": { } and update the composer.

This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
first, edit the code laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php

```
if (! ($this->app instanceof CachesConfiguration && $this->app->configurationIsCached())) {
        $config = $this->app->make('config');
        
        $configkey = $config->get($key, []);
        $configkey = is_array($configkey) ? $configkey : [$configkey];

        $config->set($key, array_merge(
            require $path, $configkey
        ));

    }
```

save it.
and run composer install.